# Average path length in random DAG

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, network

Suppose I have a random directed acyclic graph (DAG). By random I mean that edges are drawn uniformly at random so that the adjacency matrix is lower triangular with i.i.d. entries.

Is there any result on the average path length between two nodes of this DAG (e.g. between source and sink)? I know there are results of this kind for random graphs, but I can't seem to find anything for DAGs.

Comment: What you are describing is (at least in terms of the adjacency matrix) the lower triangular part of an Erdos-Renyi graph. Since you didn't mention the word "weighted" anywhere, the only two "states" an edge can be in is "present" or "not-present", which is a Bernoulli distribution (or a coin flip if you want). The direction of the edge is dictated by the restriciton that the adjacency matrix has to be lower triangular. By insisting that the probabilities have to be iid, the edges really appear with a fixed probability $p$ independently of each other, which is essentially the Erdos-Renyi model.